# Pegar o valor do meu id gerado com o push no firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Pessoal como faço para percorrer esses ids que gerei através do push e que eu consiga pegar o valor desse id pq futuramente vou precisar usar para a hora q o usuario clicar numa lista eu passar de parâmetro essa id para otra tela para eu poder carregar essa parte de informações ali [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReferenceFromUrl("https://appassistencia-8e7b9.firebaseio.com/empresa");
```

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                final String areaAtuacao = (String) dataSnapshot.child("areaAtuacao").getValue();
                final String empresaCidade = (String) dataSnapshot.child("empresaCidade").getValue();
                final String empresaEstado = (String) dataSnapshot.child("empresaEstado").getValue();
                final String empresaImagem = (String) dataSnapshot.child("empresaImagem").getValue();
                final String empresaNome = (String) dataSnapshot.child("empresaNome").getValue();
```

estou conseguindo pegar o id aq com a String s, mais na primeira vez ele vem nulo e com um id a menos no final.

```
           System.out.println(s);
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://appassistencia-8e7b9.appspot.com/imagens").child(empresaImagem);

                try {
                    final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "png");

                    storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Log.e("Test", "success!");
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            items.add(new Empresa(empresaNome, areaAtuacao, empresaCidade, empresaEstado, bitmap));

                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            System.out.println(s);
            }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }});




recycler.setAdapter(new EmpresaAdapter(items, new EmpresaAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(Empresa item) {


        startActivity(new Intent(EmpresaActivity.this, Activity_Tab_Empresa.class));


    }
}));
```

}}

Answer (score 1):

A String `s` indica a key do elemento anterior. O primeiro `s` é NULL porque não tem nenhuma key antes da primeira key na database. E seguindo essa lógica, o último `s` será sempre a penúltima key.

A key do elemento actual pode ser obtida através do DataSnapshot:

```
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey(); 
        }
```